# Order squad mates to activate electronics skill in Mass Effect 1

Tags: mass-effect

I'm playing through the first Mass effect game and I'm the vanguard class which isn't good at using the electronics skill. I got to a part where there was the option to activate a plasma containment chamber to kill some bugs inside instead of fighting them head on. I had Tali with me and she has plenty of ranks in the electronics tree.

**How can I order my squad mates to use the electronics skill on objects that I can't?**

Comment: I'm always a soldier who has no Electronics or Hacking skills and unless early on i spent points on those with Kaiden on them there was things i'd miss on Eden Prime, but that was lockers and doors. after Eden Prime i always focused on those skills, one on Tali and the other on Gerus and i could purge the Rachnii who were located at door to the entrance to the Labs on Noveria (i am assuming that's where your talking about)

Comment: Yes, that is the part I am talking about. I am confused about the controls of how to get tali to activate the trap. I fiddled around with the command screen and I understand how to get them to use their combat skills but I wasn't able to get her to go to the terminal. I'm on PC since this question is related to controls.

Comment: apart from the skills they learn, Electronics and *Decryption* (not Hacking, my mistake) are passive, so if you came to a console that says "Average Electronics/Decryption" you'll get either a "skill is to low" or the button to use to interact just under it, though this is on the 360 and it's been a while since i played Mass Effect 1 so i might be a bit off (i remember key points of Noveria cause the boss battle there was a b**** on higher difficulties but not their finer details)

Comment: @Memor-X Ah, so I saw the skill is too low message which meant that none of my squad mates had the necessary skill high enough. Thanks. If you make your comment an answer I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electronics skill is a passive skill that is only 'usable' by Shepherd when dealing with locks and the such. For the rest of your team-mates, it's just useful in unlocking other skills and passive combat abilities once it gets to certain levels.

**EDIT**

As @Memor-X mentions it's also possible that these passive stats are calculated on an average party wide basis. So even if you upgrade the skill just for one character, it's possible that you can open locks and perform hacks above Shepherd's skill level

Answer (score 4):

The *[electronics](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Electronics)* or *[decryption](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Decryption)* skills are passive apart from the abilities you unlock when leveling them up. when it comes to interacting with consoles/lockers in the environment you can't task your squad to do it for you.

I play as a Soldier who has neither skill and with my squad i always have Tali and Gerus, both have Electronics and Decryption skills which i normally focus on one from each of them and i am still able to unlock/open almost anything, so it appears that consoles/lockers in the game which require these skills are based off from the party's skill (unsure if it's the highest value or the party's total value) when you interact with them

Evidence to this is in the Eden Prime Mission when playing as a Solider, unless you spend points on Kaiden who is the only one in the party who has both skills (if you are a Soldier), you'll be unable to open the door after the first encounter with Husks where you find those scientists (one female who praises "the maker" that your humans (which seems like a Dragon Age reference) and one male who speaks of "a Turian" (Seran) as a Prophet of Destruction, a Dialog Option has you knock him out) or the lockers by the beacon.

When you approach an object which requires one of these skills you are given the object's name and underneath (on 360) you will either have the A button appearing and next to it Easy/Average/Hard Electronics/Decryption if your skill is high enough or you have "Skill too low" if it's not

Answer (score -2):

I'm sorry but i didn't know which system you were playing on so i covered all bases. this will access the teammates talents when you select one it will use that ability

> To access the party's talents, press and hold RB (R1). Use the left
>   thumbstick to browse each member's abilities, and press A (cross) to
>   queue an ability up as an action, which will be used when you release
>   RB (R1). You can also press X (square) to map the ability, but note
>   that there is no way to unmap it. Tap RB (R1) whenever you want to
>   quickly activate it in combat. Weapon abilities are interchangeable --
>   for example, if Marksman is mapped and you are carrying a shotgun with
>   Carnage unlocked, tapping RB (R1) will activate Carnage.
>
> HUD Screen (PC) Edit  PC HUD Screen The PC version uses a HUD screen
>   instead of the Power Wheel. The screen is split into three sections:
>   On the right and left of the screen, the player can view the talents
>   and abilities of the squad, and issue order by clicking with the mouse
>   on the talent, weapon, or squadmate orders icons. On the bottom, the
>   player can view Shepard's talents and abilities and, by clicking with
>   the mouse, select what ability to use, or weapon to swap to. The
>   player can also right-click and hold the button while moving the
>   mouse, to aim the crosshair to target a specific opponent.